# sql timeout on view

Tags: sql, ms-access

We have an Access application in our office that takes data from SQL Server Management Studio 2012 different views (order tables joined with other tables from different companies) and put them in a single Access table for statistics. Now the problem is that when the view becomes complicate, if I execute it from view design it gives error after 30 sec and Access gives same error when I open the view from Access so I cannot transfer data.

I changed the timeout for query and designers so if I execute a query from the view I have no problems but but this timeout has no effects on the view.

Here is my View:

```
SELECT     dbo.ordiniqdopolib.DATAconsegna, dbo.ordiniqdopolib.Fornitore,
           dbo.ordiniqdopolib.HOTEL, dbo.ordiniqdopolib.ORDINE, 
           dbo.ordiniqdopolib.PRODOTTO, dbo.ordiniqdopolib.NUMEROS, 
           dbo.ordiniqdopolib.COSTOUNITARIOS, dbo.ordiniqdopolib.COSTOTOTALES,
           dbo.ordiniqdopolib.CONSEGNATO, dbo.ordiniqdopolib.IDDOCTRASP, 
           YEAR(dbo.ordiniqdopolib.DATAconsegna) AS anno, dbo.ordiniqdopolib.napoli, 
           dbo.ordiniqdopolib.CONTRNAP, dbo.REGDOCT.NDOC, 
           dbo.ordiniqdopolib.ID, dbo.ordiniqdopolib.UTENZA, 
           dbo.ordiniqdopolib.COMPPERIODO, dbo.ordiniqdopolib.COMPANNO, 
           dbo.ordiniqdopolib.dataov
FROM dbo.ordiniqdopolib 
INNER JOIN dbo.REGDOCT 
   ON dbo.ordiniqdopolib.IDDOCTRASP = dbo.REGDOCT.ID
WHERE (dbo.ordiniqdopolib.Fornitore <> 'Inventario Napoli') AND 
      (dbo.ordiniqdopolib.ORDINE > 0) AND 
      ((dbo.ordiniqdopolib.CONSEGNATO = - 1) OR (dbo.ordiniqdopolib.ORDINE < 0)) AND
      (dbo.ordiniqdopolib.CONTRNAP = 0)
```

Any suggestions on how to avoid the 30-second timeout?

Comment: Can you show us the view?

Comment: ordiniqdopolib is a view itself with about 70.000 rows regdoct is table with 55.000 rows. View between them goes in timeout

Comment: Aside from the fact that the query is ugly, all you need to do is set the timeout to a different interval.  After you assign db = CurrentDB, add this line: db.QueryTimeout = 120.  This will extend your timeout to 120 seconds, or 2 minutes.  However, you should also try to optimize that query.

Comment: Thank You Johnny, this is not a query, it's view of Sql server Management. If I write a query, can I connect to it with msaccess?

Comment: a pass through query in ms access gives timeout error either

Comment: You're going to need to run the query using VBA.  This way, you can set db.QueryTimeout.  There's no other way I know of to extend the timeout length beyond the default 30 seconds.

Comment: yes but running in VBA is very slow